# Conditionally showing an element in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to make a `div` visible if there is an element on the page. For example:

If `('#some_div')` is on the page, I want to do a  `('#another_div').show();`

What's the syntax to make this happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/), like this:

```
if($('#some_div').length) $('#another_div').show();
```

[`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) returns the number of results the selector found, if it found any it's greater than 0 (`true`) and `false` otherwise.

---

Alternatively if you need to *hide* it, e.g. so it works both ways, you can use [`.toggle(bool)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) like this:

```
$('#another_div').toggle($('#some_div').length > 0);
```

This works regardless of the initial state, it'll hide it if `#some_div` isn't not there, and show it if it is.

Comment: What?  `.length` gives 0 if there are no elements.

Comment: @strager - I'm not following, he wants to show it only if the other element's on the page, so `.length` would be greater than `0` meaning a `true` to the `if()`.  If it's not there, `.length == 0` and the `.show()` doesn't run.

Comment: if(document.getElementById('some_div')){$('#another_div').show();}

Comment: "`.length` returns the number of results the selector found, if it found any it's greater than 0 (`true`) and `false` otherwise."  This reads, "If the number of results is greater than 0, `.length` the number of results (which evaluates to `true`); otherwise, it returns `false`."  This is wrong.

Comment: @strager - Sorry if it's not 100% clear from the first half of the sentence, `0 ~= false` just as `>0 ~= true` in JavaScript.  You may treat `0` as `false` in the case of an `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to checking for `.length`, you can use `.each`:

```
$('#some_div').each(function () {
    $('#another_div').show();
});
```

Just make sure there is only one element in your initial selector.

Comment: Why would you ever want to use an iterator for a single element?

Comment: @Gert G, It's a way.  Not necessarily the best way.  This can be chained and the `.length` method cannot (easily) be chained, for example.

Comment: But it's overkill for what the OP was asking. ;)